# How to make this script also remove certain items from recommended in Windows 11

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, windows-11

I have this powershell script that will remove (not delete!) certain items from the recent files section in Windows 11 File Explorer.

However I ALSO want it to remove certain recent files from the Windows 11 start menu recommended section.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
$Namespace = "shell:::{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}"
$QuickAccess = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$RecentFiles = $QuickAccess.Namespace($Namespace).Items()
$FilteredFiles = $RecentFiles | ? {$_.Path -like "*C:\CertainDir*"}
$FilteredFiles | % {$_.InvokeVerb("remove")}
```